# Update a database value if a video is selected?

Tags: php, wordpress

I will try to explain this, I have a button where I can upload and select a video to add to a post. And I have a input field which I can put in a duration (in seconds). I have made a function which pulls the length of the video from the database, and this length I want to put in the database under `slide_duration`. And if a video isn't selected I want it to work as it usually do, you can put in a custom value (in seconds) or you can leave this input empty (which makes it revert to the standard value).

The related PHP looks like this:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['slide_duration'] ) && is_numeric( $_POST['slide_duration'] ) && $_POST['slide_duration']  >= 1 ) {
    $slide_duration = intval($_POST['slide_duration']);
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'slide_duration', $slide_duration );
}
else {
    delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'slide_duration' );
}
```

This is how it looked before I touched it. It deletes `slide_duration` if no value is entered, this is how I need to keep it, to make it revert to the default value if nothing is put there. 
I now added this part after the above code:

```
if ( isset( $_POST['background-video'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, 'slide_duration', $video_meta['length'] );
        }
```

This will update the `slide_duration` in the database when a video is selected. But I cannot manually set the time in the input field, it always reverts to `0` when saving/updating the post. If I put the code above the original, I can put in whatever value I want in the input, but selecting a video won't update `slide_duration` any longer.

For more context, this is how the input looks:

```
<?php
    $slide_duration = isset( $theme_stored_meta['slide_duration'] ) ? intval($theme_stored_meta['slide_duration'][0]) : '';
?>
<input type="number" name="slide_duration" value="<?=$slide_duration?>" min="1" step="1" style="width: 70px;" /> <?=__('seconds', 'theme')?>
```

Hope I have explained well enough and provided enough of the code to get a clear picture of this.

EDIT: Tried this too:

```
    if ( isset( $_POST['slide_duration'] ) && is_numeric( $_POST['slide_duration'] ) && $_POST['slide_duration']  >= 1 ) {
    $slide_duration = intval($_POST['slide_duration']);
    update_post_meta( $post_id, 'slide_duration', $slide_duration );
    }
    elseif ( isset( $_POST['slide_duration'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'slide_duration', $video_meta['length'] );
    }
    if ( is_null( $_POST['slide_duration'] ) ) {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'slide_duration' );
    }
```

Comment: Maybe because `$_POST['background-video']` is always set, hence the `slide_duration` meta value is always the `$video_meta['length']`?

Comment: I only want the length of the video to replace the database value `slide_duration` when a video is selected, hence the `if ( isset( $_POST['background-video'] ) )`, this isn't always set, the meta_key always exists, but there is no value set if there is no video selected.

Comment: So, `$video_meta['length']` is the database value, right? And if a video is selected, the database value will always *override* the `input` value (i.e. `$_POST['slide_duration']`)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct! I edited my first post. Tried the code in that post. And it almost works, but it wont delete `slide_duration` if it is NULL. And when it doesn't delete `slide_duration` the input value is set to 0, and it won't save because I don't allow 0 seconds.

Comment: Are you sure it (i.e. the meta data `slide_duration`) doesn't get deleted? Perhaps the problem is with the `$theme_stored_meta`? Try to `var_dump( $theme_stored_meta )` and inspect the key/value pairs. And btw, in your edit, I think the `elseif` is for `$_POST['background-video']` and not `$_POST['slide_duration']`..

Comment: I mean, `$theme_stored_meta['slide_duration']` is probably always set even though the meta data `slide_duration` has already been successfully deleted. Perhaps you should check the `function` that sets the `$theme_stored_meta` value (i.e. `$theme_stored_meta = this_function( ... )`).

Comment: When I check the postmeta section of the database I can see that the `slide_duration`gets deleted from the database and that post id. But I don't understand where I go wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit confused myself. So I think you should first check if `$_POST['background-video']` is set, then check if `$_POST['slide_duration']` is set, and finally delete the `slide_duration` meta data if applicable. I.e. you said, "*I now added this part after the above code*"; now put that code *before* the "the above code". Or I can post an "answer" if you want or if what I said is confusing..

Comment: Could you post an answer? I am still a bit confused, have been trying for hours now.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working finally!

I don't really know what did it, but this is working:

```
    if ( $_POST['slide_duration'] == NULL ) {
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, 'slide_duration' );
    }

    if ( isset( $_POST['slide_duration'] ) && is_numeric( $_POST['slide_duration'] ) && $_POST['slide_duration'] >= 1 ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'slide_duration', (int) $_POST['slide_duration'] );
    }

    if( isset( $_POST[ 'background-video' ] ) && $video_meta['length'] >= 1 ) {
          update_post_meta( $post_id, 'slide_duration', $video_meta['length'] );
    }
```

Thank you very much Sally CJ