# Use PHP inside a jQuery .val?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Is it possible to get a value from PHP in jQuery? I have the following PHP:

```
$attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $_POST[ 'background-video' ] );
$video_meta = get_post_meta( $attachment_id , '_wp_attachment_metadata', true );
```

And I want to use the value `$video_meta['length']` inside a jQuery that right now looks like this:

```
jQuery('input[name=slide_duration]').val("PHPVIDEOMETALENGTH");
```

Is this possible with jQuery?
EDIT: This is in a separate .js file which is enqueued.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, as you have a separate `.js` file, you can not use PHP in it. Because the server will not treat it as a php file or code.

But you can do this by another way around,

put one hidden tag in the same page (which sould be a php file):

```
<input type="hidden" id="slide_duration" value="<?php echo $video_meta['PHPVIDEOMETALENGTH'] ?>">
```

And then using jquery, get its value in JS code.

```
var videolength = $('#slide_duration').val();
```

Comment: @jockebq have you checked this out?

Comment: Thank you @jockebq for accepting my answer. Happy to help. :-)

Comment: Yes, that one works, but I noticed it doesn't work in my situation. Because the `$video_meta['length']` isn't served until the post is saved, so nothing is input in the field. Just thought I could solve this with jQuery, instead of my other solution that I cannot make work, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50017950/update-a-database-value-if-a-video-is-selected?noredirect=1#comment87061008_50017950

Comment: Oh, ok. then you can do this in two parts, first make ajax request to get the length of the video and then put its value in the hidden field and then save the post along with the video itself. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I didn't know it was possible. How would you do this, do you have any example?

Comment: I don't have example but I have done such thing before. So, you can submit the video file with ajax request and get its length in php (create a separate function in php to consider the length only) and respond it to ajax and using jquery bind its value to the hidden field we created. And then while submitting the entire form, submit that length too and get in the final function where you are actually creating post.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can use `PHP` in a `JavaScript` file is if you serve that file through `PHP`. For example, your `PHP` file should be like:

```
<?php
   header("Content-Type: application/javascript");
   require "path/file.js";
?>
```

Then, you can simply write your `PHP` code inside the `js` file:

```
jQuery('input[name=slide_duration]').val("<?= $video_meta['length'];?>");
```

To load the `PHP` file, you can use a `script` element just as you would do with a `JavaScript` file.

Answer (score 0):

assign the value to the js `var` before the `separate.js` file

```
<script>var meta_length = '<?=$video_meta['length'];?>'</script>
<script src="separate.js"></script>
```

**separate.js file**

```
$(function(){    
    jQuery('input[name=slide_duration]').val(meta_length);    
});
```

Comment: He already mentioned that he is having the jQuery code in a separate `js` file.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay, before he didn't mention. now i have updated

Answer (score 0):

you can set `$video_meta` in a `div` or `span` in `php` file.

Eg:

```
 <span id="video_meta_vale" style="display:none;"><?php echo $video_meta;?></span>
```

And then just retrieve it from `js` using `id`

Eg:

```
 var t = $('#video_meta_vale').html();
 jQuery('input[name=slide_duration]').val(t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

## First set the value inside the hidden field ,then get in js.

```
 $video_meta = get_post_meta( $attachment_id , '_wp_attachment_metadata', true );

<input type="hidden" value=<?php echo $video_meta; ?> id="video_meta">

<script>
var video_meta = $('#video_meta').val();
alert(video_meta);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery in PHP**

```
<?php

    $attachment_id = attachment_url_to_postid( $_POST[ 'background-video' ] );
    $video_meta = get_post_meta( $attachment_id , '_wp_attachment_metadata', true );

    /* echoing <script> */
    echo "
    <script>

        $(function()
        {
            $('input[name=slide_duration]').val({$video_meta['length']});
        });

    </script>";

?>
```